# C programming Luhn algorithm

Tags: c, getchar, luhn

I have tried to write a program in C to check Luhn algorithm for credit cards, but it doesn't work. I think I do not have quite clear how `getchar()` works, but this program looked sensible to me. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you in advance for any help with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char x;
    int n, sum, i, c;
    sum = 0;
    printf("Insert the number of digits: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Insert the digits: ");
    for(i = n; i > 1; i = i - 1){
        x = getchar();
        if(i%2==0) 
            if(2*x < 10) sum = sum + 2*x;
            else sum = sum + 2*x - 9;
        else sum = sum + x;
        i = i - 1;
    }
    c = (9*sum)%10;
    x = getchar();
    getchar();
    if(x == c) printf("Last digit: %d,\nCheck digit: %d,\nMatching",x,c);
    else printf("Last digit: %d,\nCheck digit: %d,\nNot Matching",x,c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` reads one *character*. Therefore, the `x = getchar();` in the loop is not good because

- It firstly read a newline character if you enter that after the first "number of digits".
- It will read a character, not an integer. Character codes typically differ from the integer the character represents, and it may affect the check digit calculation.

Instead of `x = getchar();`, you should do this in the loop:

```
scanf(" %c", &x); /* ignore whitespace characters (including newline character) and read one character */
x -= '0'; /* convert the character to corresponding integer */
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I generally avoid using `getchar()` and go for `scanf` as well, however, in this case, I dropped it because I would have to insert the number one digit at time and then pressing `enter` whilst I would like to insert the whole number all at the same time. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @Logos Won't this program accept such input?

Comment: No, I write the long number and the program is waiting for me to insert the other characters

Comment: @Logos Isn't it because you wrote `getchar();` after the loop to wait for another character?

Comment: No, I had removed it as soon as I had introduced the `scanf` one. Also, if I insert the numbers one at time, followed by `enter` it works

Comment: My bad, I had put `%d` rather than `%c` and it was treating the input as integers rather than characters. However, it still does not work, because it reads the penultimate digit as last rather than the last one

Comment: @Logos You have duplicate `i = i - 1;` and wrong condition `i > 1`. It seems you should remove one of `i = i - 1` and change the condition to `i >= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 16

void luhn_algorithm();
int main(){
    int a[N];
    int i;
    printf("type the card number:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    luhn_algorithm(a);
}
void luhn_algorithm(int *a){
    int i,multiply=1,m,sum=0,total=0;
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
            multiply=a[i]*2;
            if(multiply>9){
                while(multiply>0){
                    m=multiply%10;
                    sum+=multiply;
                    multiply/=10;
                }
                multiply=sum;
            }
        }
        else if(i%2==0){
            multiply=a[i]*1;
            if(multiply>9){
                while(multiply>0){
                    m=multiply%10;
                    sum+=multiply;
                    multiply/=10;
                }
                multiply=sum;
            }
        }
    total+=multiply;
    }
    if(total%10==0){
        printf("\nthis credit card is valid ");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nthis credit card is not valid");
    }
}
```

this is the program i made to check if credit card number is valid or not try this out.
I took the numbers in an array and then multiplied it according to their position and added them all if the last digit of the added total comes out to be 0 that means the card is valid otherwise its not.
check it out if theres something wrong please tell me.